# How to modify file under .zip file at git Repository

Tags: c#, git, github, devops, nuget-package

I have one git repository where I have to modify one file under that zip folder.
I'm looking a way to modify file over repository only. I know below one options:

1. download zip file and make changes and push it back [this is not working because my zip file is 11 mb and administrator not allowing me to increase the size which is currently 10 mb from the project setting in devops]

Is there any other way I can follow and modify the zip file content.?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, git will compare multiple versions of files, work out the differences, then compress everything.

By storing a file that's already compressed you are preventing git from storing multiple similar versions efficiently.

If you need a zip file, create it in your build script, not your source code.